# Sending an email using phpmailer drupal 6

Tags: 6, emails

How do I use the phpmailer module. I have it installed and my test email sends. However the [php mailer tutorials](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial#2) show examples for using the module outside of Drupal. I want to place some code within a node to quickly fire off an email to myself when x happens.

or is it better to use the durpal mail function, I am using drupal 6, however this is not part of a module but instead will be placed in a node.

Comment: you can use rules to send email according to particular event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using drupal_mail for sending email from Drupal. That will make sure Drupal can control your mails. For example say, you are using some module like [Re-Route Email](https://drupal.org/project/reroute_emai) or [maillog](https://drupal.org/project/maillog).

```
  $params = array(
    'subject' => t('Client Requests Quote'),
    'body' => t("Body of the email goes here"),
  );


  drupal_mail("samplemail", "samplemail_html_mail", "me@site.com", language_default(), $params, "admin@site.com");

/*setting up our mail format, etc in hook mail*/
function hook_mail($key, &$message, $params)
{
    case 'samplemail_html_mail':
          /*
           * Emails with this key will be HTML emails,
           * we therefore cannot use drupal default headers, but set our own headers
           */
          /*
           * $vars required even if not used to get $language in there since t takes in: t($string, $args = array(), $langcode = NULL) */
          $message['subject'] = t($params['subject'], $var, $language->language);
          /* the email body is here, inside the $message array */
          $body = "<html><body>
              <h2>HTML Email with Drupal</h2>
              <hr /><br /><br />
              {$params['body']}
              </body></html>";
          $message['body'][] = $body;
          $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
          break;
}
```

You would invoke this in your code somewhere. Or else you can use the [rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to send email as per some events or actions in the site.

If you still want to use PHP Mailer, you have module to do that [here](https://drupal.org/project/phpmailer).

you can see a screencast on using rules to send email [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh3B8Lp8TIc).

Comment: So I can place this in a node? and what module is it I need to make this code work? Thanks

Comment: You should not place it in a node, even though it will work. Ideally, any logic or code should gointo template.php file. Or else to create a custom module to handle it. 

For example, if you want to fire an email each time a content is viewed, you can make this a function and call it in the page_preprocess_function or else if you can use any other hooks to write a condition to call the function when needed. When do you want the mail to be send?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code to send email using drupal_mail() function, if it may help you.

```
            <?php

                            function astha_menu() {
                                $items['custom-astha'] = array(
                                    'title' => t('Sending Mail!'),
                                    'page callback' => 'custom_astha',
                                    'access callback' => 'user_access',
                                    'access arguments' => array('Send Mail'),
                                );
                                return $items;
                            }

                            function custom_astha() {

                                $form['custom_form'] = drupal_get_form('custom_astha_form');
                                $output = drupal_render($form);
                                return $output;
                            }

                            function custom_astha_form() {
                                $form['email'] = array(
                                    '#type' => 'textfield',
                                    '#title' => 'UnRegister User Email',
                                    '#size' => 20,
                                    '#required' => TRUE,
                                );

                                $form['file'] = array(
                                    '#type' => 'file',
                                    '#name' => 'file',
                                    '#title' => 'Attach any file!!',
                                );

                                $form['submit'] = array
                                    (
                                    '#type' => 'submit',
                                    '#value' => t('SEND'),
                                );

                                return $form;
                            }

                            // to send mail

                            function astha_send_mail($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file) {

                                // move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'upload/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                                $params = array(
                                    'subject' => $subject,
                                    'body' => array(token_replace($body, array('callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE)),),
                                    'attachment' => array(
                                        'filecontent' => file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['name']),
                                        'filename' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
                                );
                                drupal_mail('custom', 'information', $to, language_default(), $params, $from);
                            }

                            function custom_astha_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
                                $ind_user = $form_state['values']['email'];
                                $to = (string) $ind_user; // to e-mail address
                                $from = (string) variable_get('site_mail', 'asifiqbal929@gmail.com'); // from e-mail address
                                $subject = "abc"; // subject of e-mail
                                $body = "xyz </br>Faithfully yours,<br/> [site:name] team";
                                $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
                                // here we call our mailing function
                                astha_send_mail($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file);

                                drupal_set_message('Mail to ' . $ind_user . ' has been sent.');
                            }

                            function custom_astha_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
                                $mail = $form_state['values']['email'];
                                if (!valid_email_address($mail)) {
                                    form_set_error('submitted][email_address', t('The email address appears to be invalid.'));
                                }
                            }

                            function custom_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
                                switch ($key) {
                                    case 'information':
                                        $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
                                        $message['body'] = $params['body'];
                                        $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment'];
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

        ?>
```

Comment: This code has to go into a module right? I was looking to place my code in a node. Though would it be possible to call the module in the background from my node, so that when X occurs on my node, can I call the email module in the background, instead of just placing some code in that if statement to send mail.

Comment: This is a custom module that I developed for creating a form on a menu callback that sends email by clicking on submit button. Yes you can call this function in a particular node and rest is same as above.

Comment: @Tom can you let what is X? You can definetely call this function when something occur.